Finding the frictional force between 2 objects moving with same acceleration

This is a problem I faced when reading a textbook.
Lets imagine we have a wooden block of mass M (2kg) on a trolley of mass m (20kg) which is kept on a smooth floor. The frictional coefficient between the block and the trolley are 0.25 (not given if this is the static frictional coefficient or kinetic frictional coefficient) So assuming both are 0.25, Lets consider the following scenario.
If we apply a force 2N force to the wooden block. (a force less than the limiting frictional force).
The limiting frictional force between the 2 surfaces is 5N. In this case, the wodden block does not move so both the block an the trolley travels with the same acceleration.
The common acceleration of the system is,
$$F=ma\iff
a=2/(20+2)\iff
a=o.o9 m/s^2
$$
Now since the force applied is less than the limiting frictional force, the frictional force should be equal to the applied force. So it should be 2N. But when I isolate the trolley and try to find the frictional force acting on the trolley by the block,
$$
F=ma\iff
F=20*0.09\iff
F=1.8N
$$
I get 1.8N. What am I doing wrong.
Thank you in advance.

Voting to reopen. This is a conceptual question and so allowed by policy.

@gandalf61 No. "What am I doing wrong" is not conceptual at all. It is check-my-work.


since the force applied is less than the limiting frictional force, the frictional force should be equal to the applied force

That's your mistake. The applied force must accelerate both the block and the trolley. Some of the applied force gets "used up" in overcoming the inertia of the block (i.e., in accelerating the block). The remnant is what acts, through friction, to accelerate the trolley.

What you are missing is the free-body diagram which tells you which force acts on which body and in what sense.

Due to Newton's 3rd law, friction acts positively on the cart and a negative manner on the block.
The equations of motion, derived from Newton's 2nd law, are
$$ \begin{aligned}
   F_{\rm applied} - F_{\rm friction} & = M a \\
   F_{\rm friction} & = m a
\end{aligned}$$
which are two equations to be solved for the two unknowns $F_{\rm friction}$ and $a$.
$$ \begin{aligned}
 F_{\rm friction} & = \frac{m}{M+m}  F_{\rm applied} \\
 a & = \frac{F_{\rm applied}}{M + m}
\end{aligned}$$
We interpret the above as the applied force acts on both bodies to produce the acceleration $a$ (second equation) and the frictional force between the bodies represents the fractional part of the mass of the cart relative to the total mass (first equation).
